# In Ksh Shell use FIND to search through symbolic links but ignore certain directories

Tags: shell, unix, find, ksh

I am trying to search for *.csv files in file system. There are symbolic links in certain directories that i am looking through, but i want to ignore certain directories since they result in nasty long time consuming cycles.

```
find -L "location" -name "*.csv >> find_result.txt
```

How can i tell find to ignore certain directories while keep looking at symbolic links in others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-prune` to tell `find` not to descend into a given directory.  For instance:

```
find -L location -name 'dontLookHere' -prune \
              -o -name 'orThereEither' -prune \
              -o -name '*.csv' -print
```

Comment: I used find /usr/abc -L -name './ignore_dir' -prune -o -name "*.csv" -print >> myfiles.txt    but it still gives me an error message saying find: bad option -L. Can -L and Prune be used at the same time

Comment: sorry, @user1035818 - have to put -L first, because it's an option, not a predicate.  Fixed above.

Comment: Also, `-name` takes a bare filename; if you want to prune at specific pthanames (like "./ignore_dir", but go ahead and descend into any other directories that happen to be named "ignore_dir"), use `-path` instead.

Comment: did not work using path, instead used -name " * dirname  *". thanks for the response, finally got it to work

Answer (score 0):

```
find dir -wholename dirtoskip -prune -o [rest of your find command]
```

or

```
find dir \( -wholename dirtoskip -o -wholename another \) -prune -o [rest of your find command]
```

Comment: Probably fine, other than it doesn't follow symlinks, but `-wholename` is less portable than `-path` in that more versions of find(1) support the latter than the former.  (Though there are still older versions that don't support either one...)